# How do I send a click to a JavaFX Toggle Button?

Tags: java, events, javafx, click, togglebutton

I have a toggle button which I need to "click" when I double-click another node.
I know that the event I have setup is working : When I double-click the control, the event I have that is supposed to be "clicking" the toggle button fires, but what I have it execute is not working:

```
(ActionEvent E) -> {
    Launcher.this.ButtonsForm.btnOptions.setSelected(
        !Launcher.this.ButtonsForm.btnOptions.isSelected()
    ); Launcher.this.ButtonsForm.btnOptions.fire(
    ); E.consume();
}
```

The toggle button has an event handler tied to its `onAction` that is supposed to show a form when the button is toggled on, and then when the form is closed the button goes back to its unselected state.

What is the proper method to go about accomplishing this?

Comment: I haven't tested this but it looks like you're first flipping the selected state of the toggle button, and then firing an action event on it (which will also flip the selected state). You probably need to just do one thing or the other.

Answer (score 0):

I test ToggleButton with this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class NewFXMain extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ToggleButton btn = new ToggleButton();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        Button btt=new Button();
        btt.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
               // btn.setSelected(true);
               // btn.arm();
                btn.fire();
              //  btn.setSelected(true);
                 event.consume();
            }
        });


        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        root.getChildren().add(btt);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

After this test according to @James_D you can use only fire() function eventually with arm() if isn't armed.

```
(ActionEvent E) -> {
 Launcher.this.ButtonsForm.btnOptions.fire(); 
 E.consume();
}
```

I hope helped you